# Watching for FileSystem Events on MacOS 10.10

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, file, xcode6

I'm trying to code a little command line tool using Xcode (under MacOS 10.10) that watches a specific folder and informs me about changes to files in that folder. 
I'm following the guide given in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html

Here is my current code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>



void mycallback(
                ConstFSEventStreamRef streamRef,
                void *clientCallBackInfo,
                size_t numEvents,
                void *eventPaths,
                const FSEventStreamEventFlags eventFlags[],
                const FSEventStreamEventId eventIds[])
{
    int i;
    char **paths = eventPaths;

    printf("Callback called\n");
    for (i=0; i<numEvents; i++) {
        int count;
        /* flags are unsigned long, IDs are uint64_t */
        printf("Change %llu in %s, flags %lu\n", eventIds[i], paths[i], eventFlags[i]);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //  @autoreleasepool {
    // insert code here...
    NSLog(@"Starting to watch ");


    /* Define variables and create a CFArray object containing
     CFString objects containing paths to watch.
     */
    CFStringRef mypath = CFSTR("/Users/testuser/");
    CFArrayRef pathsToWatch = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (const void **)&mypath, 1, NULL);
    void *callbackInfo = NULL; // could put stream-specific data here.
    FSEventStreamRef stream;
    CFAbsoluteTime latency = 3.0; /* Latency in seconds */

    /* Create the stream, passing in a callback */
    stream = FSEventStreamCreate(NULL,
                                 &mycallback,
                                 callbackInfo,
                                 pathsToWatch,
                                 kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow, /* Or a previous event ID */
                                 latency,
                                 kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNone /* Flags explained in reference */
                                 );



    /* Create the stream before calling this. */
    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(stream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    FSEventStreamStart(stream);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and can be started. However, no events are being fired. I'm pretty new to Xcode and also never ever used a callback function before. So I guess that this is a pretty dumb mistake that I made.

I'd appreciate any hints that may help.

Thanks in advance
Norbert

**Update**: The code was updated with a working solution from the answer.

Comment: Just found the first bug on my own. The stream has to be started/stopped. I edited the code sample above but unfortunately it is still not working :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, after starting event stream to send events, you should call [`CFRunLoopRun`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRun).

Try to change your `while()` loop to:

```
CFRunLoopRun();
```

**Update**. My output:

```
$ ./fsevent
2015-05-17 13:51:29.718 fsevent[898:23601] Starting to watch
Callback called
Change 1165579 in /Users/baf/src/tests/, flags 66560
Callback called
Change 1165594 in /Users/baf/src/tests/, flags 66048
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I re-desigend that part of the code and started the RunLoop. However, There is no effect :-)

Comment: I actually tested your code. It gives a bunch of warnings when compiled, but it works for me with `CFRunLoopRun()`. See my output

Comment: Now I'm completely confused. On my system the only output is:      


'2015-05-17 14:01:59.293 testApp[7188:1283738] Starting to watch'   

Did you do any specific file operations while the program has been running? With other words: what kind of changes are indicated by the program?
Also: What platform/OS are you running exactly?

Comment: What you see in my output is the result of creating and deleting a file in the watched folder: `touch test` and `rm test`

Comment: Now I have it. The exact code that I have did not work, however, it was very close. Seems that the FSEventStreamStart(stream); has to come before the CFRunLoopRun(); statement.

Comment: Of course, as I wrote: "after starting event stream to send events, you should call CFRunLoopRun"

Comment: Yes, you are right. Should read answers more carefully. I also update the complete code sample above and replaced it by my current (and working) solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have *FSEventStreamRef stream;* commented out. In order to start watching events you'll want to uncomment that line. It also looks like your callback print statement is also commented out, although that appears to be just for debugging perhaps.

Comment: I uncommented the printf in the callback function. The // FSEventStreamRef stream was a relict. The stream is already declared a few lines earlier. I removed the line now. However, the code is still not working :-(